# What do Sylow 2-subgroups look like for Schur covering groups of finite simple groups?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, schur-multipliers

What do Sylow 2-subgroups look like for Schur covering groups of finite simple groups?

Are there any references in which we can find the stucture of Sylow 2-subgroups of Schur covering groups of finite simple groups?

Comment: How is this different from your question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357300/in-which-books-we-can-find-structure-information-for-finite-simple-groups-and-th ?

Comment: For the sporadic groups, I'd look in Aschbacher's SPORADIC GROUPS, although there are easier books for, say, the Mathieu groups. For the classical groups that aren't orthogonal, then you're just looking at matrix groups which are pretty easy to deal with -- Taylor's CLASSICAL GROUPS is a good option. For the orthogonal groups, you need to understand spin groups. For these and for the exceptionals I'd probably start with Gorenstein-Lyons-Solomon Vol 3 although I don't have it in front of me so can't double-check. Finally double-covers of alternating groups are covered in many places.

Comment: Thank you very much!